# Adding object to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I currently have this array

```
const items = [  
     {name: "tablet", description: "12inch", price: 700, popularity: 99},   
     {name: "phone", description: "8inch", price: 900},  
     {name: "computer", description: "32inch", price: 3000, popularity: 50},  
     {name: "laptop", dimensions: "17inch", price: 1500},             

];
```

and want to add a random popularity score between 1 and 100 for the items that currently have to entry.

My current code:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {           
if ([6 == 'undefined']) {  
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);  
    items.push(('popularity:'), (randomNum));   

gives me the array:

[

{
  description: "12inch",
  name: "tablet",
  popularity: 99,
  price: 700
}, 

{
  description: "8inch",
  name: "phone",
  price: 900
}, 

{
  description: "32inch",
  name: "computer",
  popularity: 50,
  price: 3000
}, 

{
  dimensions: "17inch",
  name: "laptop",
  price: 1500
}, "popularity:", 51, "popularity:", 38, "popularity:", 92]
```

when i console.log it,

So I am wondering how it is that I can loop through both the dimensions of the array, the rows and columns so the array would appear as:

```
{name: "tablet", description: "12inch", price: 700, popularity: 99},   
{name: "phone", description: "8inch", price: 900, popularity: 51},   
{name: "computer", description: "32inch", price: 3000, popularity: 50},   
{name: "laptop", dimensions: "17inch", price: 1500, popularity: 32},
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if ([6 == 'undefined'])` Won't say a syntax error, but complete logical error. That gets equated to `if ([false])` because two constants are not same and finally it becomes `if (true)` as it's a non empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop over the items, and add the missing field if it's not present:

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'tablet', description: '12inch', price: 700, popularity: 99 },
    { name: 'phone', description: '8inch', price: 900 },
    { name: 'computer', description: '32inch', price: 3000, popularity: 50 },
    { name: 'laptop', dimensions: '17inch', price: 1500 },
];

items.forEach(i => i.popularity = i.popularity || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));

console.log(items);
```

Since you're stating that you want a value between 1 and 100, you might want to use `Math.ceil()` instead of `Math.floor()`.

Comment: The `forEach` doesn't do anything to the main array. **Update:** Alright, you're mutating the array.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman What needs to be done to the main array?

Comment: Got it, Robby, you're mutating the array.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yeah, OP said he just wanted to add a property to the objects in the array. Didn't see a need to create a new array.

Comment: Generally I use map to create a new array, without mutating the original one. (You know, React & States)...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yeah, totally understand. Impossible to say if mutability is an issue for OP, so I just went for the more efficient approach.

Comment: No issues here. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'tablet', description: '12inch', price: 700, popularity: 99 },
    { name: 'phone', description: '8inch', price: 900 },
    { name: 'computer', description: '32inch', price: 3000, popularity: 50 },
    { name: 'laptop', dimensions: '17inch', price: 1500 },
];

const result = items.map(item => (item.popularity ? item : { ...item, popularity: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `if ([6 == 'undefined'])` - I won't say a syntax error, but complete logical error. That gets equated to `if ([false])` because two constants are not same and finally it becomes `if (true)` as it's a non empty array.

There are better ways to do this, and best thing would be a [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'tablet',
    description: '12inch',
    price: 700,
    popularity: 99
  },
  {
    name: 'phone',
    description: '8inch',
    price: 900
  },
  {
    name: 'computer',
    description: '32inch',
    price: 3000,
    popularity: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'laptop',
    dimensions: '17inch',
    price: 1500
  },
];

const result = items.map(item => (item.popularity ? item : { ...item,
  popularity: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `nullish coalescing operator (??)`

```js
const items = [
  { name: "tablet", description: "12inch", price: 700, popularity: 99 },
  { name: "phone", description: "8inch", price: 900 },
  { name: "computer", description: "32inch", price: 3000, popularity: 50 },
  { name: "laptop", dimensions: "17inch", price: 1500 },
];

const update = (arr) =>
  arr.map(({ popularity, ...product }) => ({
    popularity: popularity ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
    ...product,
  }));

console.log(update(items));
```